# Rotate with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate a simple navigation, and have it positioned to the left of the container div. However, I'm not sure how the rotate is supposed to work. For some reason, the div is not overlapping its parent and is out of site.

My desired outcome looks like this, with the text aligned to the left of the container:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ges7L/

```
.write-note-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}

.write-note-container .nav {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid pink;
}

.write-note-container .nav .rotate {
      -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */

background-color: red;
width: 400px;
text-align: left;
height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property set to `0, 0`

```
.write-note-container .nav .rotate {
    /* Other properties */
    background-color: red;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ges7L/1/)

Comment: Do you know why there is a space to the left of the rotated div? http://jsfiddle.net/ges7L/5/

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be appearing  different?

Comment: @tmyie are you using chrome? cuz I've just used general property, let me add the proprietaries as well http://jsfiddle.net/ges7L/7/

Comment: That's great. I don't understand why it would need an extra 10px? Is this something to do with the rotate?

Comment: @tmyie Because you were using `bottom` but if you use `top` you will get the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

add transform origin to control the origin of the rotation.

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ges7L/4/